# Let's encrypt + certbot: where is the private key

Tags: security, encryption, ssl, certificate, letsencrypt

I've been using `openssl` to create key and certificate for my website.
Which works fine, but leads to complaints from the browser.

Now I would like to move to Let's Encrypt to get a proper certificate.

The setup was very simple, I installed certbot and followed the tutorial on their website.

I was surprised to read that `certbot` is supposed to be used with a flag `certonly`. Intuitively, this should mean that only a certificate is created. It should ask me for an existing key during the setup. Which is doesn't, instead, it creates both a new certificate and a new key.

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d xxxx

...

Waiting for verification...
Cleaning up challenges
Generating key (2048 bits): /etc/letsencrypt/keys/0000_key-certbot.pem
Creating CSR: /etc/letsencrypt/csr/0000_csr-certbot.pem

....
```

But this key doesn't seem to exist.
If I enter the path into my server, it complains about not finding the key.

I had problems with read permissions on my certificate, solved by this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/773440/lets-encrypt-ssl-certificate-file-not-found-error-but-still-working

The solution was to change access rights.

But I'm hesitant to do that with my private key. Internet security is so complex, I'm afraid I don't really know about the consequences of changing permissions regarding something as important as the private key.

How am I supposed to use the newly generated certificate. Where can I find the corresponding private key and do I have to apply additional configuration ?

Comment: Whatever is trying to use your key needs to be able to read your key. There is absolutely no way around this.

Comment: Certbot's `certonly` actually means "just get a certificate but don't configure it", as opposed to `certbot run` which actually _configures Apache for you_. (Many users, including myself, would prefer to avoid automated configuration editing – and of course not everyone uses Apache or nginx, either.)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Ignore** the `csr` and `keys` dirs; they essentially just contain temporary files during issuance.

Certbot always puts the latest version of all certificates under **`/etc/letsencrypt/live`**:

```
/etc/letsencrypt/live
├── mail.example.org
│   ├── cert.pem -> ../../archive/mail.example.org/cert8.pem
│   ├── chain.pem -> ../../archive/mail.example.org/chain8.pem
│   ├── fullchain.pem -> ../../archive/mail.example.org/fullchain8.pem
│   └── privkey.pem -> ../../archive/mail.example.org/privkey8.pem
└── www.example.org
    ├── cert.pem -> ../../archive/www.example.org/cert7.pem
    ├── chain.pem -> ../../archive/www.example.org/chain7.pem
    ├── fullchain.pem -> ../../archive/www.example.org/fullchain7.pem
    └── privkey.pem -> ../../archive/www.example.org/privkey7.pem
```

Therefore you would configure services like this:

```
SSLCertificateFile     /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.org/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile  /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.org/privkey.pem
```

This way, services only need to be reloaded, not reconfigured, after every renew. Use certbot's "deploy hook" feature to automate permission changes, service reloads, and anything else that needs automating.